# ES6 Object of Object manipulation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Loop through the Object and filter by key. `obj` is the object I have to loop through and filter it by the given key and obtain its value alone

If the given key to filter is 'chem' then the expected result is:

```
{
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    title: 'Jedi Knight',
    age: 23,
```

}

I have a solution. But it's not very efficient. Looking for a better way to address this.

```
const obj = {
  chem: {
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    title: 'Jedi Knight',
    age: 23,
  },
  history: {
    name: 'Anakin Skywalker',
    title: 'Jedi Knight',
    age: 18,
  },
  bio: {
    name: 'Yoda',
    title: 'Jedi master',
    age: 50,
  }
};
const asArray = Object.entries(obj);

const filtered = asArray.filter(([key, value]) => key === 'chem');
console.log(filtered[0][1]);
```

Comment: `obj['chem']` has O(1)

Comment: const asArray = Object.entries(obj);

const filtered = asArray.filter(([key, value]) => key === 'chem');
console.log(filtered[0][1]);

instead of above thry below

for(const key in obj){
  if(key==='chem'){
    console.log(obj[key])
  }
}